# Why are questions with answers showing up in the Unanswered Questions tab?

Tags: discussion, questions, unanswered-questions

This is my first post to meta, so perhaps there's a really simple answer for this... but when I go to the Unanswered Questions tab, I see mostly questions that have answers provided.

Does Unanswered mean that a question has not been EXPLICITLY marked with a correct answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well not exactly.

Unanswered doesn't necessarily mean that there are no answers, nor that no answer has been accepted, but that there are no *upvoted* answers.

Asking a question and being given a response that nobody deems worthy of voting for is not really much different than asking a question and not receiving any responses. Both are equally unhelpful to the person who asked the question.

There are also Unanswered questions that have recieved No Answers. That is more what you are referring to here, I think.

You can choose what type of 'Unanswered' questions you want to look at. Once you select the 'Unanswered' link in the top blue bar the tabs below update to allow you to change the view of questions you're looking at. `My tags`, `newest`, `Votes` and `No answers`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!