# Blue top bar hidden underneth message banner (UI Bug)

Tags: bug, user-interface

Just saw this, and have not been able to find it already reported anywhere, so here goes (turn off adblocker, and open an incognito tab, to reproduce):

[image: screenshot]

The message banner ("Join us in building...") overlays the blue top bar, but it also kind of pushes the buttons down, outside of the blue bar, which just looks wiered. It does go back to the way it should be once you close the message bar:

[image]

Latest Chrome, Linux.

(Also, the logo & buttons are not centered in the blue bar, which also just looks wrong. There's a lot more space above the buttons & logo than below...)

Comment: Note that the same bug affects the [Photography](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions) site. Also, I'm now thinking that [another bug I noticed on this site](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3234/83293) might be related, although the cause for that would have been the increase to the height of the top bar, not the banner.